# The seven churches that were condemned; did any of them repent?

Tags: revelation

In Revelation, there were seven churches that were told of their actions and were told to repent of their sins or there will be consequenes. Are there any written words that told whether the seven churches actually repented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, of the seven churches in Revelation individually addressed, not all are condemned/rebuked.

The church in Smyrna ([Rev 2:8-11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%202&version=NASB)) is not condemned. Likewise, the church in Philadelphia is not rebuked ([Rev 3:7-13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%203&version=NASB)).

We do know that those churches no longer exist today, so at some point their candlestick *was* removed. Whether or not the 5 did repent at least to some degree, we are not told.

Comment: Interesting note: Of the cities from which the seven churches were named, only the two you mention as not having been rebuked have survived as continually inhabited to the present day. A couple others have been re-founded at or near the original sites, so for example there is a modern day city of "Bergama" near were Pergamam was, but the original city was destroyed and abandoned in the course of history after those letters to the churches in them.

Comment: Now @Caleb, you wouldn't be bragging about your home of Izmir / Smyrna, would you? :)

Comment: And, for the record - if you ever get the chance to visit these cities, you should.  Especially Laodecia - possibly one of the most amazing experiences I've ever had.  But, that's getting into travel.stackexchange.com...

Comment: @AffableGeek - I asked a related question on travel.SE yesterday: [Recreating Paul's missionary trips (from The Bible) / itinerary optimization and visas](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9229/1689)